# How to create indexed column names in a loop in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a function to automatically assign a number of new column names for a new dataset.

The reason is that I need some way to bind my predictions to my initial dataset. Sklearn does not have any easy way to do that.

I have already tried to create a function, however it only prints an error:

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1440, 90), indices imply (1440, 1)

This means that i do not use the function properly when defining new column names.

```
def column_printing(x):
    i=0
    for i in range(x):
        print('prediction', i+1)
        i+1
resultTestDataset = pd.DataFrame(y_test, columns=[column_printing(predict_length)])
```

lets say that:

```
predict_length = 3
y_test = [5,6,7],
         [3,2,1]
```

I want a dataframe which looks the following:

```
prediction1, prediction2, prediction3
5,6,7 
3,2,1
```

Comment: Is your python higher or equal to 3.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can assume your `y_test` is a `numpy array`.

You can use the following:

```
predict_length = 3
y_test = np.reshape(np.array([5,6,7,3,2,1]), (2,3))

df = pd.DataFrame(y_test, columns=['predicition{}'.format(x+1) for x in range(predict_length)])

print(df)
   predicition1  predicition2  predicition3
0             5             6             7
1             3             2             1
```

If your python version >= 3.6, we can use `f-strings`

```
predict_length = 3
y_test = np.reshape(np.array([5,6,7,3,2,1]), (2,3))

df = pd.DataFrame(y_test, columns=[f'predicition{x+1}' for x in range(predict_length)])

print(df)
   predicition1  predicition2  predicition3
0             5             6             7
1             3             2             1
```

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to store the elements [5,6,7,...] row wise ; such  that if I have multiple arrays each array goes into each columns

Answer (score 0):

this will help

```
# a simple function to do the column name creation
column_print = lambda col_len : ['prediction' + str(i+1) for i in range(col_len)]

y_test = [5,6,7],[3,2,1]
y_test = np.array(y_test) # convert y_test to a numpy array so you can use the shape 
#method
size_y = y_test.shape
resultTestDataset = pd.DataFrame(y_test, columns=column_print(size_y[1]))
print(resultTestDataset)
```